# Problems with LibreOffice 3.6.0.4 rendering MS Office 2007 documents

Tags: libreoffice

I currently have 10.04 installed with the latest version of LibreOffice.

Before, I used to work in Windows 7 and MS Office 2007. Most if not all of my documents is in Word and Excel format.

Now I am in LibreOffice, and know about the small conversion changes, when opening up a document created in Word in LibreOffice Writer.

The one problem I have is the rendering. My pages seems to get larger - LibreOffice Writer is creating auto spacing in-between lines where there weren't any spaces, making my document that is a 2-page long, to 4 pages.

Sometimes after re-editing in LibreOffice Writer, I can only get up to 3 pages, because there aren't any space left on the pages.

Everything fits to a 2-page document in Word, but can't fit to 2 pages in LibreOffice.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Are the fonts in your source document compatible?

One of the first things I would try is to understand if you are using compatible fonts in your source document as Ubuntu (libre office) may be substituting these and causing the effect you are experiencing.  MS Core fonts are **not** installed as standard in ubuntu and you have to do this manually

**Go to the terminal (Ctrl-Al-T)and type in**

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

This will give you the core fonts, but if there are other TrueType fonts that you want installed, it is as easy as copying the font files to the ~/.fonts/ directory.

Comment: Stephen,

I used the terminal link you gave me. Let me see what is happening, and if my problem is still there. Hope everything is ok.

Thank you for that terminal sudo link, other wise I wouldn't be able to install it, as I don't know it.

Comment: @TimBotha:  Keep in mind that this will install "common" fonts such as arial, times new roman etc.  If you source document is using some kind of fancy font, your issue may continue to persist.  Good luck

Comment: I doubt that there was fonts that was fancy. Other wise that one or two have to be then something else. thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are some compatibility issues between MS Word and LO Writer with *.docx file format. If you can, it is better to convert your *.docx files into *.doc (MS Word 97/2003) file format, because *.doc files shows a higher compatibility between MS Word and LO Writer.